# Eclipse C debugger with custom Makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, makefile

I try eclipse for a project which involves custom libraries.

I have the following Makefile:

```
all: clean test_debug 

CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include/librdkafk
CFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib
LDFLAGS += -lrdkafka

test_debug: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test_debug.c -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) 

clean:
    rm -f test_debug
```

And the C code is simply:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I go to run->debug configuration and in the left part on the "Main page" I check the Build configuration, I have only: Select Automatically, default, Use Active. So no debug and release. Therefore Ecplise is not able to debug the code. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The `all` target probably does not need to have the `clean` dependancy unless you want to completely rebuild the objects and executable each time.  the `all` and the `clean` targets do not produce files of the same name, so there needs to be, near the top of the makefile, `.PHONY: all clean`

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse, when creating a project,

after opening the 'new' pull down menu item

after selecting 'project'

after entering the project name and selecting type of project, click 'next'

then the 'select configurations' page is displayed

click both the 'debug' and the 'release' configurations

highlite a configuration, for instance 'debug'

click 'advanced settings'

select the `text file encoding`, normally UTF-8

select the 'text file line delimiter', (for my system 'linux')

click 'apply'

click 'ok'

click 'finish'

back in the main screen views

right click the property name in the 'project explorer' window

click 'build configurations'

click 'select active'

click the configuration 'release' or 'debug' that you want to use

---

When the desired configuration is not currently set:

in the 'project explorer' window

right click the project name

click 'properties'

click 'c/c++ build'

click 'manage configurations'

click 'new'

enter a configuration name (for instance 'debug'

click 'import predefined'

use pull down menu to right of import predefined to select the configuration type

click 'ok'

click 'ok;

click 'OK;

Comment: then when you select "build configuration" there will be a menu item: 'select active'    click that  and select which build configuration you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution does not work when you import a project with the related make file.

Comment: It seems odd that the properties of a imported project cannot be changed.  I would have expected it to be no problem to change the properties, after importing.   Does this mean the files in the project belong to a different user, who did not set the files for `group` or `world` read/write access?